# Why is the number of rows lower by one than the number of columns in my grid?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a (drawing) application which has an area to draw and inside the area I have a grid layout which has rows and columns of course.
The problem is, I am having one more column than row, for example when the size of the layout is 16x16, I have 16 columns and 15 rows.
I wrote the script in JS that is connected to an HTML file.

```js
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
    const resizeButton = document.querySelector('.button1');
    const randomButton = document.querySelector('.button2');
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('.button3');
    const boxWidth = 400; //the width of the drawing area is 400px
    let randomBrush;
    let size, nsize;
    let init = (function() {
        randomBrush = false;
        const defSize = 16;
        nsize = defSize;
        mainContainer.style.display = 'grid';
        mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr';
        container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
        container.style.gridRowStart = '3';
        container.style.display = 'grid';
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'auto';
        container.style.width = '350px';
        container.style.border = '2px solid gray';
        container.style.justifySelf = 'center';
        randomButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
            if (randomBrush === false) {
                randomBrush = true; 
            } else {
                randomBrush = false; 
            }
        });
        resizeButton.addEventListener('click', resize);
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', clear);
        draw(defSize);
    })();
    function draw(n) {
        size = n;
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + size + ', 1fr)';
        container.style.gridAutoColumns = boxWidth/size + 'px';
        container.style.gridAutoRows = boxWidth/size + 'px';
        for(let i = 0; i < size*size; i++) {
            let element = document.createElement('div');
            element.textContent = '';
            element.onmouseenter = function() {
                if (!element.classList.contains('colored')) {
                    if (randomBrush) {
                        element.style.background = randomColor();
                    } else {
                        element.style.background = 'white';
                    }
                    element.classList.add('colored');
                }
            };
            container.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
    function randomColor() {
        let r, g, b;
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        string = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
        return string;
    }
    function resize() {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        nsize = prompt('What should be the new size of the drawing are? (E.g type "32" for 32x32)');
        if (nsize > 0 && nsize < 129) {
            draw(nsize);
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a num between 0 and 128');
            resize();
        }
    }
    function clear() {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        draw(nsize);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Etch-a-sketch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='main-container'>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Created by chriskoder</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="button1">Resize</button>
                <button class="button2">Random</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class='button-under'>
                <button class="button3">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well the answer of Scott Marcus made me closer to the real solution.
The final solution is to add the size itself to the size * size.
Why?
Because as Dmitry Reutov answered, the first row is there, but it doesn't have a height, so I should add one whole row which is practically 17 (in case of size 16) but since the first row is unvisible because of it's height, there is only 16 visible.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const resizeButton = document.querySelector('.button1');
const randomButton = document.querySelector('.button2');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.button3');
const boxWidth = 400; //the width of the drawing area is 400px
let randomBrush;
let size, nsize;
let init = (function() {
    randomBrush = false;
    const defSize = 16;
    nsize = defSize;
    mainContainer.style.display = 'grid';
    mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr';
    container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
    container.style.gridRowStart = '5';
    container.style.display = 'grid';
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'auto';
    container.style.width = '350px';
    container.style.border = '2px solid gray';
    container.style.justifySelf = 'center';
    randomButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
        if (randomBrush === false) {
            randomBrush = true; 
        } else {
            randomBrush = false; 
        }
    });
    resizeButton.addEventListener('click', resize);
    clearButton.addEventListener('click', clear);
    draw(defSize);
})();
function draw(n) {
    size = n;
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + size + ', 1fr)';
    container.style.gridAutoColumns = boxWidth/size + 'px';
    container.style.gridAutoRows = boxWidth/size + 'px';
    for(let i = 0; i < (size*size)+size; i++) {
        let element = document.createElement('div');
        element.textContent = '';
        element.onmouseenter = function() {
            if (!element.classList.contains('colored')) {
                if (randomBrush) {
                    element.style.background = randomColor();
                } else {
                    element.style.background = 'white';
                }
                element.classList.add('colored');
            }
        };
        container.appendChild(element);
    }
}
function randomColor() {
    let r, g, b;
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    string = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    return string;
}
function resize() {
    container.innerHTML = '';
    nsize = prompt('What should be the new size of the drawing are? (E.g type "32" for 32x32)');
    if (nsize > 0 && nsize < 129) {
        draw(nsize);
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a num between 0 and 128');
        resize();
    }
}
function clear() {
    container.innerHTML = '';
    draw(nsize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row exists but it has 0 height, may be the problem is here

```
container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
container.style.gridRowStart = '3';
```

try to give them the same value - 2 and 2, if not then learn more about grid settings

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your loop is set to go as long as your counter is less than `size*size`, which means that if `10` were entered, the loop would go `99` times, not `100`.

Change the line to:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= (size*size); i++) {
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
    const resizeButton = document.querySelector('.button1');
    const randomButton = document.querySelector('.button2');
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('.button3');
    const boxWidth = 400; //the width of the drawing area is 400px
    let randomBrush;
    let size, nsize;
    let init = (function() {
        randomBrush = false;
        const defSize = 16;
        nsize = defSize;
        mainContainer.style.display = 'grid';
        mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr';
        container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
        container.style.gridRowStart = '3';
        container.style.display = 'grid';
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'auto';
        container.style.width = '350px';
        container.style.border = '2px solid gray';
        container.style.justifySelf = 'center';
        randomButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
            if (randomBrush === false) {
                randomBrush = true; 
            } else {
                randomBrush = false; 
            }
        });
        resizeButton.addEventListener('click', resize);
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', clear);
        draw(defSize);
    })();
    function draw(n) {
        size = n;
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + size + ', 1fr)';
        container.style.gridAutoColumns = boxWidth/size + 'px';
        container.style.gridAutoRows = boxWidth/size + 'px';
        for(let i = 0; i <= (size*size); i++) {
            let element = document.createElement('div');
            element.textContent = '';
            element.onmouseenter = function() {
                if (!element.classList.contains('colored')) {
                    if (randomBrush) {
                        element.style.background = randomColor();
                    } else {
                        element.style.background = 'white';
                    }
                    element.classList.add('colored');
                }
            };
            container.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
    function randomColor() {
        let r, g, b;
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        string = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
        return string;
    }
    function resize() {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        nsize = prompt('What should be the new size of the drawing are? (E.g type "32" for 32x32)');
        if (nsize > 0 && nsize < 129) {
            draw(nsize);
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a num between 0 and 128');
            resize();
        }
    }
    function clear() {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        draw(nsize);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Etch-a-sketch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='main-container'>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Created by chriskoder</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="button1">Resize</button>
                <button class="button2">Random</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class='button-under'>
                <button class="button3">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "size*size, which means that if 10 were entered, the loop would go 99 times, not 100."  No, it loops from 0 to 99 which means exactly 100 times, your example loops 101 times: from 0 to 100. I'm surprised how it could solve the problem, just accidently

Comment: Well, that's actually interesting

Comment: Okay, I tried out something and you know what in the last row only the first cell is paintable so if I move the mouse to the last 9 (if I set 10 to the size) I can't paint the last 9